# How do I map WAV files to integers and play their sounds in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, wav

I have been trying to find a way to map WAV sound vectors read in by `wavread` stored in variables `y1`,`y2`,.. with integers `1`, `2`,..  I currently have code set up that uses `if/else` statements where depending on what integer is input from the user, the sound associated with that integer key is heard.  However, I'd like to remove the excessive use of the `if/else` statements. Is there such a way to do that in MATLAB?

The code I have written so far is given below:

```
y1=wavread('E:\sound\one.wav');
y2=wavread('E:\sound\two.wav');
y3=wavread('E:\sound\three.wav');
y4=wavread('E:\sound\four.wav');

t=input('prompt:');
if t==1
    sound(y1,40000);
elseif t==2
    sound(y2,40000);   
elseif t==3
    sound(y3,40000);
elseif t==4
    sound(y4,40000);
else
    disp('wrong input');
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It seems to do what you want...

Comment: I wanted to get rid of the if-elseif-else part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is your desire to provide a mapping given an integer to a sound signal, the easiest thing to use is a cell array - especially if each sound file is not the same length.  You can do something like this:

```
y1=wavread('E:\sound\one.wav');
y2=wavread('E:\sound\two.wav');
y3=wavread('E:\sound\three.wav');
y4=wavread('E:\sound\four.wav');

sounds = {y1, y2, y3, y4};
```

You can then access each sound by the integer index that corresponds to it.  For example, if you want the first sound, just do:

```
s = sounds{1};
```

You can change the index to whatever sound you want.

---

Now, if you want to adapt this to your current code to get rid of the `if/else` statements, that can be done by just playing the right sound given the cell array.

Something like this:

```
y1=wavread('E:\sound\one.wav');
y2=wavread('E:\sound\two.wav');
y3=wavread('E:\sound\three.wav');
y4=wavread('E:\sound\four.wav');

sounds = {y1, y2, y3, y4};

t = input('Prompt: ');
if t < 1 || t > numel(t)
    disp('Wrong Input');
else
    sound(sounds{t}, 40000);
end
```

The last statement allows you to remove the multiple `if/else` statements and consolidate it into one `if/else` statement instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for! :D

Comment: @Meraki - No problem at all.  Good luck!